# Flutter: Trouble with single characters & custom font

Tags: fonts, dart, flutter

I am attempting to use a custom OTF font, [linja pona](https://github.com/janSame/linja-pona/), in a Flutter application to render certain words in a special script.

I include the font in my project, list it in my pubspec.yaml, and create Text widgets like this:

```
Text(word, style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'LinjaPona', fontSize: 18.0))
```

And it works perfectly for most words!

In the image below, you can see the symbols properly displayed next to each of these words.

It does not work for single letter words, however. For instance, "a" and "e" are words that also have special script renditions, shown, below, but they don't get rendered in the linja pona font.

Does anyone have any idea what the issue could be? I wonder if it has to do with the Text widget maybe stripping white space away? (If I try to use the linja pona font in a text editor, I type "e" and then have to press "space" to get the word to change into the script version.)

Thanks for any help.

Most words rendered into script correctly:

[image: words have character]

"a" and "e" also have script renditions:

[image: "a" and "e" also have special script renditions]

Comment: What Flutter version are you using? Have you tried with `master` channel. I think there were some fixes recently that might be related.

Comment: I tried updating to master and it doesn't seem to have fixed anything, but thank you very much for the suggestion!

Comment: Then I'd suggest to create a bug report with a minimal reproduction.

Comment: I [started an issue for the font itself](https://github.com/janSame/linja-pona/issues/6), and someone opened a PR that seems to have fixed the problem! So I guess the issue was with the font itself and not Flutter. I know very little about fonts and thought it could go either way.